# Does OpenGL change vertices in memory when you apply transformations?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, transformation, vertex

So let's say I have a single vertex (to make things easy) in my program, (0, 0, 0). Right at the origin. I render a single frame with a simple translation matrix, moving the vertex two units down the x-axis. The vertex is rendered accordingly. Does the same vertex now show up in the VRAM as
(2, 0, 0)? I've read that it's important to load all the respective identity matrices in OpenGL every time a frame is rendered--and I assume that's because everything would continually move, rotate, etc. further and further, implying that applying transformations DOES modify actual data, not just the appearance onscreen.

Comment: OpenGL 2.0 with fixed pipeline or OpenGL 4/ES with custom shaders? I.E do you ever make calls to glVertex?

Comment: Modern OpenGL with custom shaders.

Comment: If memory serves, I thought you didn't have to load all the identity matrices in modern opengl since there is no state machine with modern opengl.

Comment: If you are interested in learning OpenGL I would highly recommend this website http://www.marekknows.com and you can purchase download credits to view his video tutorials. I've been a member since 2007-08 and I have learned so much through him; not just learning OpenGL or Game Engine development but many different algorithms and methods to doing all kinds of programming tasks. I also learned elegant application design and it has strengthened my C++ skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link on wiki about the mathematics involved with Transformation Matrices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix this will give you an understanding of the math behind the scenes. Another way to look at this is also on the lines of linear or vector algebra. So what happens under the hood when you render a scene is that all of the vertex (pixel) data is sent from the CPU to the GPU to be rasterized and drawn to the screen. This is your batch process or render call, now you also have a frame function that will happen x amount of times per second which will give you your frames per second. So if you are rendering at say 60 FPS then these pixels, vertices, triangles etc., will be drawn 60 times each second. When you apply a transformation to this set of vertices what happens here is you have a transformation matrix that is being multiplied to your model view projection matrix. MVP * T which this will be saved back into your existing MVP matrix if this is how you have your calculations set up. There are some differences between which version of OpenGL you are using as you go from OpenGL v1.0 Pure CPU calls up to v4.5. As far as I know after version 3.2 or 3.3 I don't remember which version off hand you have to implement the MVP yourself where versions greater than v1.5 where shaders were first introduced was handled for you already. Here is the documentation on OpenGL https://www.opengl.org/ and on the main page there will be a topic that says documentation from there you can either select OpenGL Registry or which ever specific version you want to look at. From here you can read their documentation about the OpenGL API since this site covers everything that is available in their API. So as you begin to understand this process, yes the actual coordinate data for these vertices does change, however it will not continuously change unless you are incrementing a static type variable with a factor of time thus giving you some kind of simulation of movement or animation. If you apply only a single transformation then these pixels, vertices, triangles, etc., will either Rotate, Translate, Scale, or Shear depending on which Transformation you are applying. I will tell you that the order of these operations does matter, but I will not tell you which order they are, that will be for you to read up on and to figure out. These reason this does matter is due to the fact that not every Matrix Multiplication has a valid Inverse Matrix. The Identity is used for reasons such as round off errors and floating point precision, so that if you happen to apply say 1,000 transformations in a matter of about 10 seconds, you do not have astronomical errors. This should be enough to point you in the right direction and also serve as a guide as to how the OpenGL API works.

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot from your answer, but I still don't understand why the vertex data doesn't continue to change even if you don't reset the matrices. I don't remember the different matrix layouts off the top of my head--but say you set a translation matrix to move 2 units down the positive x-axis, as in my question. Every time you render a frame without resetting that matrix, why doesn't the vertex move two units FURTHER down the x-axis? Is the matrix automatically reset after being used once?

Comment: As I stated when you do a transformation matrix operation on a set of data that matrix multiplication happens and is stored back into the original matrix you started with. This is not a continuous operation. You have a single pixel vertex  A and you translate it 2 units in any direction what you will see is the resulting translation of that original pixel (vertex) drawn to the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, OpenGL is just an API definition. An implementation can do whatever it wants as long as it meets the specifications.

That being said, the answer to your question is generally: **NO**. It's hard to picture how storing transformed vertices back into the memory that also contained the original vertices would ever make sense.

The original vertex positions are passed into the vertex shader, where they are processed, which can include transformations. Once they exit the vertex shader, the transformed positions will most likely be stored in some kind of cache or dedicated on-chip GPU memory until they are processed by the next steps of the pipeline, which includes perspective division, application of the viewport transform, and rasterization. Once those vertex processing steps are completed, the transformed vertices can be discarded. They may stay in a cache for a little longer, for possible reuse of the processed vertex in case the same original vertex is used again. But they are not stored in any persistent way.

The way I interpret it, what you heard about having to reset the matrices for each frame was probably a misunderstanding. If you want to apply the same matrices in the next frame, you don't have to do anything at all.

What they were most likely talking about is related to how the matrix stack in legacy OpenGL works. Most calls that modify the current matrix, like `glTranslatef()`, `glRotatef()`, etc, are applied incrementally to the current matrix. For example, if you call `glRotatef()`, the rotation is combined with the transformation that was already on the matrix stack. The result it that your newly specified rotation is applied to the vertices first, followed by the transformations that were already on the matrix stack.

Based on this, if you want to specify transformations from scratch at the start of each frame, you will call `glLoadIdentity()` to reset the current transformation on the matrix stack before you start specifying your new transformations. Or you can use `glPushMatrix()`/`glPopMatrix()` to save and restore the desired state of the matrix stack.

If you use what many people call "modern OpenGL", meaning that you don't use the legacy fixed pipeline functionality, you don't have to worry about any of that. The matrix stack is gone for good, and you get to calculate your own transformation matrices, and pass them to your shader code.

Comment: @Sam Claus Use this feedback as well for Reto Koradi makes excellent points! I didn't get involved with the stack, gpu and cache memory but what he states is what is happening within the hardware and the difference between legacy OpenGL where everything is done on the CPU verses newer versions of OpenGL that uses Shaders on the GPU.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if my question was badly designed--in the tutorials I was following, a little bit of legacy OpenGL was used, then modern. Now I have answers for both version! Although I intend to use strictly modern OpenGL from this point forward. But these answers leave me with one more question, if you don't mind. I would like to almost completely avoid using the CPU for physics, model movement, collision detection, etc. Using modern OpenGL, can I actually edit the data in VRAM--or will the CPU have to keep track of things?

Comment: Like if I have my avatar at point A, and I use the GPU to visually move it to point B, the avatar would typically still be physically at point A until I update its location in RAM, using the CPU.